# How can I open my page without .html address?

Tags: url-rewriting

I am a beginner, so sorry for this question.

the main page name is: index.html

and a second page is for example second.html

The issue:
I can just open it on the browser by using the full name includes .html means:
[www.example.com/second.html](http://www.example.com/second.html)

If I type just: [www.example.com/second](http://www.example.com/second) it is not possible to open the page.

Can you maybe tell me what I do wrong?

Comment: It is the responsibility of the web server to determine what content to return when a client asks for a URL. Your question can't be answered without knowing what web server you are using.

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:html], [tag:css], [tag:dns] and the [tag:web] tag says "Do not use this tag"!. Please take more care in selecting the tags you associate with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your htaccess, try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```